# MS Access .mdb import and save to a node that has content type depend's of the table name

Tags: ms-access, drupal-6

In my work, the end user in a Drupal site needs to upload a file that has a .mdb extension without convert it to csv file that has 4 table sheet. Every row in the table sheet should be saved as a node in the database and have fields match the columns in the table and the content type of the node depend on the name of the table in the file.

Can this be done?  How can I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to tell you that you had to do your own module which will do the whole process from a-z , you can open node import module only to know how it create the nodes .

there's a big difference between what you want and the node-import module one of them is in CSV the fields is comma separated but in your case .mdb is not comma separated you had to fetch on each table sheet and check if the table equal to any of your content types or not . then you'll create nodes in case of matched name in content types .

Another difference is in the node import you choose which column will match with your content type field .

Finally why they need so ? .. In case they need it by any mean so they had to know time and money of something like this .

that's all my knowledge .

Comment: thanx very very much  george for ur help 
but what u mean of 
"so they had to know time and money of something like this" 
????

Comment: You are welcome  :) . I mean it will take much effort from you and he'll pay money for that .

Comment: i want to you help on how i can use this MdbTools in drupal
http://devzone.zend.com/1315/reading-access-databases-with-php-and-pecl/

Comment: Sure.First i don't know it but i read your link , about my understanding it's very powerful tool that presents to you an api to database layer for access only "It can help you fetch for all tables and get the records ." . But it's very limited as it's not installed on windows supports "NIX system" . It also needs lots of steps to first install PCEl on your server also you need to make sure php build supports unixODBC .About the steps of installation as i see you have to call the server support to install it to you and you only check for the extension.

Comment: I don't think that you have to do the installation all the steps mentioned in your link are done from the server :) .

Comment: thanx goerge for your help
wish u the best

Comment: Wish this to you too :) .. Fell free to contact me in anything you need :) . Don't forget to rate .